# Define header filename as variable in Arduino/C

Tags: c, arduino

In arduino IDE i want to define a filename as variable. Then insert it into a header for uploading a file to a flask application as variable.

Filename should be as example: 1

Hardcoding the filename as following works well:

```
if (https.begin(*client, "https://hanspeter//")) {
    https.addHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
    https.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"1\"");
```

I tried different options to define a variable, but always get errors:

**Option 1**:

```
const char *thisisaname = "1";
https.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="thisisaname);
```

**Error**:
unable to find string literal operator 'operator""thisisaname' with 'const char [18]', 'unsigned int' arguments

**Option 2.**

```
const char *thisisaname = "1";
https.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + thisisaname + "\""));
```

**Error:**
invalid operands of types 'const char [19]' and 'const char*' to binary 'operator+'

**Option 3.**

```
const char *thisisaname = "\"1\"";
https.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="thisisaname);
```

**Error:**
invalid operands of types 'const char [19]' and 'const char*' to binary 'operator+'

Comment: what language is this really? In c++ you have `std::string`. In arduino c++ dialect there is `String` i believe. In C its also possible but different.

Comment: Arduino seems to have a C/C++ dialect, where most commands will work but only less libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way of doing that would be a `#define`. It is memory efficient and won't take up much flash. Then you can also take advantage of string literal concatenation:

```c
#define SO "http://stackoverflow.com/"
#define URL "questions"
...
surf_to(SO URL)
```

which expands to `surf_to("https://stackoverflow.com/questions")`